# Cron Expression - Every day in two different hours (13:30 and 17:40)?

Tags: cron, quartz.net, cronexpression

I want to create a Cron expression to run "Every day, at 13:30 and 17:40". As hard as I tried I only managed to achive this by combining the results of two Cron Expressions:

- 0 30 13 ? * *
- 0 40 17 ? * *

Is there a way to describe this in **one Cron expression**?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the only way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question - no, there is no way to describe this schedule in one cron expression.
But, if you have equal minutes, you can use this;

`30 13,17 * * *` - this will fires at 13:30 and 17:30.